# Django MySql setup

Tags: python, mysql, django

I set up Mysql5, mysql5-server and py26-mysql using Macports. I then started the mysql server and was able to start the prompt with `mysql5`

In my settings.py i changed database_engine to "mysql" and put "dev.db" in database_name.

I left the username and password blank as the database doesnt exist yet.

When I ran `python manage.py syncdb`, django raised an error

'django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dynamic module does not define init function (init_mysql)`

How do I fix this? Do I have to create the database first? is it something else?

Comment: Are you using the Python version that's also from MacPorts?  Typically you can't use the system version of Python with MacPorts-obtained extension modules.

Comment: No I was using python 2.6 that I installed myself. I also have virtual enviroments working as I am using Pinax. Shall I install python 2.6 from macports? anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install MySQLdb: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mysql-python/

This can be a painful process depending on your setup.  See other discussions on SO regarding MySQLdb install on mac os x:

[How to install MySQLdb (Python data access library to MySQL) on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x)

EDIT:  Sorry, skimmed past the fact that you already installed MySQLdb via py26-mysql, but this error seems to point to something that went wrong with that install.  I've had lots of problems with MySQLdb on Mac OS X, always something different I have to do to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

`syncdb` will not create a database for you -- it only creates tables that don't already exist in your schema.  You need to:

- Create a user to 'own' the database (root is a bad choice).
- Create the database with that user.
- Update the Django database settings with the correct database name, user, and password.

Comment: when I create the database from the mysql prompt, where does it store the database? how do I find the path for it?

Comment: @Ali, that depends upon your OS and your configuration files.  On most Unixes, you'd find the database files under /var/lib/mysql.  For more details, see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/installation-layouts.html