# Installing MySQLdb Python Architecture Error

Tags: mysql, architecture, 32bit-64bit, mysql-python

I am trying to install MySQLdb python and am having trouble getting it to work because I get an architecture error.

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/jkeesh/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/jkeesh/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-x86_64.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

This has been a common question, and I have read many, many sources including:

[Python MySQL wrong architecture error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061277/python-mysql-wrong-architecture-error)

http://www.mechanicalgirl.com/view/installing-django-with-mysql-on-mac-os-x/

[Django + MySQL on Mac OS 10.6.2 Snow Leopard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904039/django-mysql-on-mac-os-10-6-2-snow-leopard)

[Installing MySQLdb on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531958/installing-mysqldb-on-mac-os-x)

and many other links.

It appears that the problem is a 32-bit 64-bit mismatch, but I'm not sure what the right combination is, or what exactly the mismatch is.

I have installed from pip, from Mac ports, and built from the source. I have tried setting the `ARCHFLAGS` to both `i386` and and `x86_64`.

I have tried setting `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT` and `VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_64_BIT` preferences.

I am running Mac OS X 10.6.6

I have mysql installed in `/usr/local/mysql`

```
$ file $(which ./mysql)
   ./mysql: Mach-O executable i386
```

I have mysql version `5.5.12`

I have `64 bit Python 2.6.6.`

My system architecture is:

```
>>> platform.platform()
'Darwin-10.6.0-i386-64bit'

$ file $(which python) 
   /opt/local/bin/python: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

If there are any links you can point me to or suggestions to try I would really appreciate it. I'm kind of at a dead end and getting the same "wrong architecture" error no matter what I try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my own question, so hopefully this can be of help to people with similar issues.

I believe I had a 32-bit mysql installation.

I uninstalled all versions of mysql that I had

I went back and installed mysql 5.1 from the source, but I think a mysql 5.1 x86_64 bit dmg or binary would work also.

I used this make command from this post http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/

I had permission issues and finally got it working using

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

I installed MySQL-python 1.2.3c1 from here

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.3c1

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this in your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH="/usr/local/mysql/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib/
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_64_BIT=no
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
```

Comment: I believe I tried that options with VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER, but that wasn't the problem.