# Installing MySQLdb on Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos

From this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.4) I downloaded MySQLdb and run following two commands

```
sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

I also define the environment path in .bash_profile as follows

```
export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/:$PATH"
```

The **problem** is after running above command I don't see any error, but when I try the following command in python shell I see error

```
import MySQLdb
```

**Error Log:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4-py2.7-macosx-10.5-x86_64.egg/_mysql.so
  Reason: image not found
```

My Operating system - Mac 10.9.5 and Python version - 2.7.5 :: Anaconda 1.6.1 (x86_64)

**How I can install MySQLdb on Mac OS X 10.9.5, 64bit?** Thanks.

Duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531958/installing-mysqldb-on-mac-os-x), but this is for 32bit Mac OS X Snow Leopard.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mysql has officially supply the driver for python called mysql connector,
And Mysqldb has not been in maintenance,
I suggest you install the offical one and Django has supported it,
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/,
Then in your settings.py:
Just Change the engine name

```
    DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'user_data',
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django',
        'USER': 'mysql_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'priv4te',
        'OPTIONS': {
          'autocommit': True,
        },
    } 
}
```

And the guide for developer
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html

Have fun