# Help installing MySQLdb for Python under Mac OS X

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-python

I know this has been asked several times, but after a few hours of trying, there is no way to make this work.

I've installed MySQL 32bits from a dmg file and MySQL-python-1.2.3.

I followed [this steps](http://friendlybit.com/tutorial/install-mysql-python-on-mac-os-x-leopard/), but when I run `python setup.py build`, these errors come up:

```
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-fat-2.6/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/usr/local/mysql-5.5.12-osx10.6-x86/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-fat-2.6/_mysql.o -Os -g -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -arch i386
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.12-osx10.6-x86/include/my_config.h:326:1: warning: "SIZEOF_SIZE_T" redefined
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:9,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pymacconfig.h:39:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from _mysql.c:36:
/usr/local/mysql-5.5.12-osx10.6-x86/include/my_config.h:419:1: warning: "HAVE_WCSCOLL" redefined
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/Python.h:8,
                 from pymemcompat.h:10,
                 from _mysql.c:29:
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6/pyconfig.h:803:1: warning: this is the location of the previous definition
_mysql.c:76: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL’
_mysql.c:90: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘MYSQL_RES’
_mysql.c: In function ‘_mysql_Exception’:
_mysql.c:120: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_errno’
_mysql.c:120: error: ‘_mysql_ConnectionObject’ has no member named ‘connection’
_mysql.c:132: error: ‘ER_DB_CREATE_EXISTS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
_mysql.c:132: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
```

......

I'd appreciate ANY help you can provide. Thanks!

Comment: It looks like the compiler cannot find the MySQL header files. Were header files included with the DMG that you installed? If so, you can point the compiler in the right direction by setting the CFLAGS environment variable.

Comment: It contained a few pkg files to install it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install MySQLdb (Python data access library to MySQL) on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [macports](http://www.macports.org/):

```
$ port search python | grep mysql
py-mysql @1.2.2 (python, devel, databases)
Python interface to mysql
py25-mysql @1.2.2 (python, devel, databases)
Python interface to mysql
py26-mysql @1.2.3 (python, devel, databases)
py27-mysql @1.2.2 (python, devel, databases)
Python interface to mysql
```

Comment: Hey, thanks! I don't know 100% what I just did, though :D If I run "import MySQLdb" from the Python CLI it doesn't find it. How can I check it is properly installed?

Comment: That command doesn't install it.  `sudo port install py-mysql` (or whichever one you want) will, though.  And `port list | grep py-mysql` will show if it's installed.

Comment: Yeah, I got it now, I'm installing and see how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

My answer here worked for me for both a 32-bit and a 64-bit Mac Snow Leopard install (on two different machines): [Installing MySQLdb for Django on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard with MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235408/installing-mysqldb-for-django-on-mac-os-x-10-6-snow-leopard-with-mamp/6852774#6852774)

Short version:

```
[user]$ sudo su
[root]# ARCHFLAGS="-arch $(uname -m)" pip install mysql-python
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to deal with the headache of a package manager on your mac, I've detailed my experience in this installation guide: http://alexandersimoes.com/journal/2011/03/04/install-mysqldb-on-mac-osx-snow-leopard/