# Installing MySQLdb for Django on Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard with MAMP

Tags: django, macos, installation, python-2.6, mysql-python

So I know this is not a new topic, but its one that nobody has seemed to be able to solve, at least not for Python 2.6 / Snow Leopard.  (The Leopard fixes I've found aren't applicable to Snow Leopard.)

Situation: I'm trying to get Django installed locally on my Mac OS X Snow Leopard laptop. (10.6.7) I have Python 2.6.1, which is what came preinstalled with Snow Leopard, MySQL-python 1.2.3, and MAMP 1.9.6.  All are latest current versions.

Without making any changes to the MySQLdb package, if I run `python setup.py build` I get hundreds or more errors, the first of which are:

```
$ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb/release.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6
gcc-4.2 -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -arch i386 -arch ppc -arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,3,'final',0) -D__version__=1.2.3 -I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/include/python2.6 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.6-universal-2.6/_mysql.o -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g
_mysql.c:36:23: error: my_config.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:38:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:39:26: error: mysqld_error.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:40:20: error: errmsg.h: No such file or directory
_mysql.c:76: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'MYSQL'
_mysql.c:90: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'MYSQL_RES'
```

and ending with:

```
_mysql.c:2422: error: initializer element is not constant
_mysql.c:2422: error: (near initialization for '_mysql_ResultObject_memberlist[0].offset')
_mysql.c: In function '_mysql_ConnectionObject_getattr':
_mysql.c:2444: error: '_mysql_ConnectionObject' has no member named 'open'
lipo: can't open input file: /var/folders/Br/Br8Yhf-IGVCaGfXw4TYRc++++TI/-Tmp-//ccFnIslh.out (No such file or directory)
error: command 'gcc-4.2' failed with exit status 1
```

So I updated my `site.cfg` file with the location of mysql_config:

```
# The path to mysql_config.
# Only use this if mysql_config is not on your PATH, or you have some weird
# setup that requires it.
mysql_config = /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config
```

Still the same error. I've spent the past two days troubleshooting, so I've done a whole bunch of other things (including the `ez_setup`, downloading .egg files, and manually changing some options in the code), but none of them have yielded any different results, so I won't bore you with all of the details. In general, there could be something obvious I'm missing, who knows? (hopefully). Python and MySQL both work fine, so one thing I have not done and was trying to avoid is a reinstall of MySQL not through MAMP.  But if anybody has reason to believe that's necessary, I'll try it.

Any help would be much appreciated!  Thanks.

Comment: No, there is no `/Applications/MAMP/Library/include` directory at all (and obviously no files in the nonexistent directory). How do I know what should be there and where can I get those files? Thanks. <br /><br />And: `$ /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config --include
-I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include
`

Comment: There is no mysql.h file anywhere in the MAMP directory, and I Spotlight searched mysql.h, and the only result was the _mysql.c file that's looking for it here and throwing the error. I had assumed in my troubleshooting that mysql.h should have been part of the MySQLdb python package, but I guess not-- it should have been part of MAMP?  Either way I have no files by that name. Running `/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config --include` prints `-I/Applications/MAMP/Library/include`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this working as you'd expect.

A couple things:

First of all, the `lipo: can't open input file` indicates a prior compile failure. The setup scripts should really be failing and showing an earlier error; I don't know why they aren't.

Secondly, MySQLdb gets all its config information from `mysql_config`. So for instance, executing `mysql_config --cflags` gives the C compiler flags. In my case it emitted `-I/usr/local/Cellar/mysql/5.5.12/include  -g`. In the absence of a `-arch` flag in there, the wrong architecture gets targeted. Also, linking architecture (in this setup file) is derived from `mysql_config --cflags` as well, so linking will target the wrong architecture.

Setting the architecture explicitly using `ARCHFLAGS` does the trick. The following script assumes that the MySQL and python builds that you are using match your machine architecture as returned by `uname -m`; if not, specify it explicitly.

```
[user]$ sudo su
[root]$ export ARCHFLAGS="-arch $(uname -m)" # or '-arch i386' or '-arch x86_64'
[root]$ pip install mysql-python
```