# import MySQLdb error

Tags: python, mysql, macos, mysql-python

Hi I have the following error when trying to import MySQLdb. Does anyone know what the issue could be?(I'm on a mac)

```
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/christopherfarm/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/christopherfarm/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Comment: It said you installed wrong architecture of mysqldb, check your downloaded version against your system's specs?

Comment: probably a 32/64 bit issue. Could you do "lipo -info /Users/christopherfarm/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so" and edit the output in?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x/1448446#1448446 for more on the installation

Comment: @cularis here's the terminal `ipo -info /Users/christopherfarm/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so
Non-fat file: /Users/christopherfarm/.python-eggs/MySQL_python-1.2.3-py2.6-macosx-10.6-universal.egg-tmp/_mysql.so is architecture: i386
`

Comment: @Mark I tried using macports like you said but am getting the following issue now http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964292/mysql-python-error-from-macports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havbe to either install an egg built for your architecture, or install from source (i.e. .zip or .tar.gz).

Comment: sorry I'm new to all this, how do I know what architecture I need and how do I make sure that I get the right one?

Comment: The "install from source" is covered in the answer that Mark linked. Cudos to him.

Comment: I tried using what Mark said but get the following problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6964292/mysql-python-error-from-macports

Answer (score 1):

Me too I had a lot of headache with MySQLdb.

If you are starting new development I would suggest to switch to the official MysQL Python Connector: (available on PyPI):

```
sudo pip install mysql-connector-python
```

or by download from:
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/

Documentation: 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-python.html

It's easy to use and also compatible with PEP 249 (Python DB API version 2.0).