# Mysql error from macports: missing mysqld.sock

Tags: python, mysql

I ran the following in the terminal:

```
sudo port install py26-mysql 
sudo port install mysql5-server
```

It seems to have downloaded and installed properly, but when I try to open mysql using `/opt/local/lib/mysql5/bin/mysql` I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/opt/local/var/run/mysql5/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Does anyone know what's gone wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you activate the MySQL server?  See the instructions under [Step 3: Install MySQL](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/MAMP).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to `/opt/local/etc/mysql57/my.cnf` the following configuration:

```
[client]
socket=/opt/local/var/run/mysql57/mysqld.sock

[mysqld]
socket=/opt/local/var/run/mysql57/mysqld.sock
```