# Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to `pip install` the `MySQL-python` package, but I get an `ImportError`.

```
Jans-MacBook-Pro:~ jan$ /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin/pip-3.3 install MySQL-python
Downloading/unpacking MySQL-python
  Running setup.py egg_info for package MySQL-python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
      File "/var/folders/lf/myf7bjr57_jg7_5c4014bh640000gn/T/pip-build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 14, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "./setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>

  File "/var/folders/lf/myf7bjr57_jg7_5c4014bh640000gn/T/pip-build/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 14, in <module>

    from setup_posix import get_config

  File "./setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>

    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser

ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/lf/myf7bjr57_jg7_5c4014bh640000gn/T/pip-build/MySQL-python
Storing complete log in /Users/jan/.pip/pip.log
Jans-MacBook-Pro:~ jan$
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what does `echo $PATH` say?

Comment: How come in 2017 I get the same error with python3?

Comment: Its 2020 and still the same

Comment: 2021 and still the same too :)

Comment: It's nearing 2023 and the issue still persists.

Comment: Its 2023 and still the same 

Comment: I don't understand why there are so many comments pointing out that it "still doesn't work", when it's clear that the project is abandoned. **It has been more than ten years** since the last release, where the readme simply claimed that Python 3 support would be added in a future version.

Comment: It's 2024 and .... still here... 

Answer (score 472, accepted):

In Python 3, [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) has been renamed to [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) for PEP 8 compliance. It looks like the package you are installing does not support Python 3.

Comment: Correct. MySQL-python does not currently support Python 3.

Comment: What are my alternatives? I tried PyMySQL3-0.5 but its very buggy, it crashes at first execute call.

Comment: @JanBirsa A quick google search found a few possibilities: if [PyMySQL](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/) doesn't work, there is [OurSQL](https://launchpad.net/oursql/), [MySQL Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/index.html), [a port of MySQL-Python](http://sourceforge.net/p/mysql-python/discussion/70460/thread/61e3a3c9), and others.

Comment: I was getting install error for all the python packages. Your Solution & discussion gave me the hint as to what could be the problem. Then I recalled that I had manually changed the /usr/bin/python from python2.7 to /usr/bin/python3.5, which actually was causing the issue. Once I reverted the same. It got solved.

Comment: A moving target on this one but I use pip3 install mysql-connector. Now available from MySQL for python3 support. release at time of typing is 2.1.3.

Comment: Just tried `sudo python3 -m pip install mysql-connector` and now it's working. Thanks for the hint @Longmang

Answer (score 470):

You can instead use the [`mysqlclient`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient) package as a drop-in replacement for MySQL-python. It is a fork of `MySQL-python` with added support for Python 3.

I had luck with simply

```sh
pip install mysqlclient
```

in my python3.4 virtualenv after

```sh
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

which is obviously specific to ubuntu/debian, but I just wanted to share my success :)

Comment: On CentOS, run "yum install python-devel mysql-devel" before installing mysqlclient.

Comment: Note that this is a GPL package, so if you use this module, you need to release your program with GPL as well.

Comment: On [*Debian*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) it is sufficient to install [`libpython3.5-minimal`](https://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=names&keywords=libpython3.5-minimal) package (`sudo apt-get install libpython3.5-minimal`).

Comment: On OSX you should run "brew install mysql" before installing mysqlclient.

Comment: I used  pip3 install mysqlclient and it worked like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: thank you for sharing your success - it helped me when I was stuck for hours and into the SO rabbit-hole :)
Now to the next problem

Answer (score 21):

Here is a code that should work in both Python 2.x and 3.x

Obviously you will need the `six` module, but it's almost impossible to write modules that work in both versions without six.

```
try:
    import configparser
except:
    from six.moves import configparser
```

Comment: Why not skip the try block and just use `from six.moves import configparser`

Comment: -1. The whole point of `six.moves` is to [*"provide a consistent interface"*](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves) to renamed modules; wrapping imports with a `try`/`except` when using `six` defeats the point. Just use `from six.moves import configparser`. Not that six is needed here; you could replace `from six.moves import configparser` with `import ConfigParser as configparser` in your `except` block and achieve the same result without needing `six`.

Comment: @MatthiasKuhn I guess the intend was to make `six` only a requirement for Python 2.X, but not Python 3.X.

Comment: @MartinThoma This defeats the whole point (as Mark Amery wrote). If the try/except check is in place there is no more reason to use `six.moves` and the native name can be used directly for Python 2 as well.

Answer (score 19):

```bash
pip install configparser
sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py /usr/lib/python3.6/ConfigParser.py
```

Then try to install the `mysql-python` again.
That worked for me.

Comment: Super idea, this should be an accepted answer although it is a geeky way.

Comment: it's better to create a link other than copy

Answer (score 12):

MySQL-python is not supported on python3 instead of this you can use **[mysqlclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient#downloads)**

If you are on `fedora/centos/Red Hat` install following package

1. `yum install python3-devel`
2. `pip install mysqlclient`

Comment: raise EnvironmentError("%s not found" % (mysql_config.path,))
    OSError: mysql_config not found

Comment: @PirateApp possibly mysql isn't install. check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7475223/mysql-config-not-found-when-installing-mysqldb-python-interface

Comment: sudo yum install python3-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.web-ster.com
 * epel: mirrors.cat.pdx.edu
 * extras: mirror.web-ster.com
 * ius: mirrors.kernel.org
 * updates: mirror.web-ster.com
No package python3-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do

Answer (score 11):

Additional info:

**Python 2x**

```
import ConfigParser
```

**Python 3x**

```
import configparser
```

Answer (score 8):

If you are using CentOS, then you need to use

1. `yum install python34-devel.x86_64`
2. `yum groupinstall -y 'development tools'`
3. `pip3 install mysql-connector`
4. `pip install mysqlclient`

Answer (score 8):

Compatibility of Python 2/3 for `configparser` can be solved simply by `six` library

```
from six.moves import configparser
```

Answer (score 7):

I was having the same problem. Turns out, I needed to install python3 devel on my centos. First, you need to search for the package that is compatible with your system.

```
yum search python3 | grep devel
```

Then, install the package as:

```
yum install -y python3-devel.x86_64
```

Then, install mysqlclient from pip

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

Answer (score 7):

Do `pip3 install PyMySQL` and then `pip3 install mysqlclient`.
Worked for me

Answer (score 3):

I got further with Valeres answer:

> pip install configparser
>   sudo cp /usr/lib/python3.6/configparser.py /usr/lib/python3.6/ConfigParser.py
>   Then try to install the MYSQL-python again. That Worked for me

I would suggest to link the file instead of copy it. It is save to update.  I linked the file to `/usr/lib/python3/` directory.

Answer (score 3):

For me the following command worked:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install mysql-connector
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50546125/6069796) solution which worked fine for me.

Basically it's to reinstall/upgrade to latest version of **mysql** from **brew**, and then installing `mysqlclient` or `MySQL-Python` from `global pip3` instead of `virtualenv pip3`.

Then accessing the `virtualenv` and successfully install `mysqlclient` or `MySQL-Python`.

Answer (score 2):

I still have this issue, so I go to /usr/lib/python3.8 and type as sudoer:

```
cp configparser.py ConfigParser.py
```

You may have another python version than 3.8.

Answer (score 2):

Following [@MaciejNg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38994435/16936415) I tried making a copy, which didn't work:

```
sudo cp ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/configparser.py ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ConfigParser.py
```

Because `configparser.py` and `ConfigParser.py` are identical, I renamed the file:

```
sudo mv ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/configparser.py ./env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/ConfigParser.py
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

how about checking the version of Python you are using first.

```
import six
if six.PY2:
    import ConfigParser as configparser
else:
    import configparser
```

Comment: This would be much simple `from six.moves import configparser`

Answer (score 1):

I run kali linux- Rolling and I came across this problem ,when I tried running cupp.py in the terminal, after updating to python 3.6.0. After some research and trial I found that changing    `ConfigParser` to    `configparser` worked for me but then I came across another issue.

`config = configparser.configparser()
AttributeError: module 'configparser' has no attribute 'configparser'`

After a bit more research I realised that for python 3    `ConfigParser` is changed to    `configparser` but note that it has an attribute     `ConfigParser()`.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error on Mac OS 10, Python 3.7.6 & Django 2.2.7. I want to use this opportunity to share what worked for me after trying out numerous solutions.

Steps

1. Installed Connector/Python 8.0.20 for Mac OS from [link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/)
2. Copy current dependencies into requirements.txt file, deactivated the current virtual env, and deleted it using;

   create the file if not already created with; `touch requirements.txt`

   copy dependency to file; `python -m pip3 freeze > requirements.txt`

   deactivate and delete current virtual env; `deactivate && rm -rf <virtual-env-name>`
3. Created another virtual env and activated it using; `python -m venv <virtual-env-name> && source <virtual-env-name>/bin/activate`
4. Install previous dependencies using; `python -m pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

base on your OS is centos   use python3
if you don't known where is configparser.py or ConfigParser.py

1. pip3 install configparser
2. find / -name "configparser.py"
3. cd /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages(base on your environment )
4. cp  configparser.py ConfigParser.py

solved the issue

Answer (score -1):

Kindly to see what is `/usr/bin/python` pointing to

if it is pointing to `python3 or higher`  change to `python2.7`

This should solve the issue.

I was getting install error for all the python packages. Abe Karplus's solution & discussion gave me the hint as to what could be the problem. 
Then I recalled that I had manually changed the `/usr/bin/python` from `python2.7` to `/usr/bin/python3.5`, which actually was causing the issue. Once I `reverted` the same. It got solved.

Comment: Reverting to Python 2 to support `MySQL-python` is overkill; use the Python 3 version of the library instead.

Answer (score -3):

This worked for me

```
cp /usr/local/lib/python3.5/configparser.py /usr/local/lib/python3.5/ConfigParser.py
```

Comment: should not do that. See answer from Abe karplus . ConfigParser has been renamed to configparser in Python3.