# i need to configure a django and mysql in pycharm IDE

Tags: mysql, django, python-3.x

i refer this http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/quickstart/django_guide.html
but getting the error while executing 
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are in the virtual environment

Then download the `md5` package from [Python mysql package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5)

OR

using pip you can install like

> pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5

Comment: what is 1.2.5 is a python version

Comment: from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

Comment: current version of python i am using is 3.4

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: iam using  python3.4 ubuntu14.04 X86

Comment: In Python 3, ConfigParser has been renamed to configparser for PEP 8 compliance. so change that accordingly

Comment: were to change or reference website

Comment: ok try this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser

Comment: SO you have two options 1 is editing the setup_posix.py.file or try installing pip install mysqlclient