# Error on install of MySQLdb

Tags: python, mysql, django

I run the following command `pip install MySQL-python`

it throws the error :-

```
Collecting MySQL-python
  Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-_79w9z_b/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-build-_79w9z_b/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-_79w9z_b/MySQL-python/
```

Comment: Seems to be same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser

Comment: try using [`mysqlclient`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient), which is a python3x-compatible fork of MySQL-Python