# MySQL with Django - Python

Tags: python, mysql, django, macos, mysql-python

I'm integrating MySQL as backend with my Django application. At the time of installation i'm running following command (using mac os)

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
start server from settings (i'm on mac os)
brew install mysql-connector-c
sudo pip install MySQL-python
```

while running last command i'm getting following error,

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/tmp/pip-build-wd69ia4g/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from setup_posix import get_config
  File "/private/tmp/pip-build-wd69ia4g/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip-build-wd69ia4g/MySQL-python/
```

I google the error and got the solutions as run following command

```
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

But it doesn't solve my error.

Can any body help me to get out of it or let me know the steps for the initial MySQL setup.

Can not getting the solution than i'm ready for the fresh installation. Post the exact steps here

Comment: did you activated your virtalenvironment?

Comment: Why are you installing both mysql-connector and MySQL-python? They are alternatives. If the first one worked, you don't need the second.

Comment: @DineshSunny Yes Activated

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Can post the command or refer me a link please. I'm  stuck from yeaterday

Comment: @PinankLakhani are you using python 3 then ConfigParser Lib is renamed to configparser. You can try this post to solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/23978968/2958795

Comment: @DineshSunny I run the following command from the post

    pip install mysqlclient

But still giving the following error
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/m4/szfv1v4s5s14vzlrpqbpxvjr0000gn/T/pip-build-p05_hq9h/mysqlclient/

Comment: A link to what? As I said, these are alternatives. You've already installed mysql-connector without problems. So stop there, and don't also try and install mysql-python.

Comment: @PinankLakhani uninstall other libraries u installed before mysqlclient. Now you can completely use this lib..Read the docs here https://mysqlclient.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: @DanielRoseman SO now i can start coading MySQL in Django app. No more installations require?

Comment: @DineshSunny 
@ DanielRoseman
Not working still :( :(

I cleared the installation from the following link

https://coderwall.com/p/os6woq/uninstall-all-those-broken-versions-of-mysql-and-re-install-it-with-brew-on-mac-mavericks

And run following command

pip install mysqlclient

getting still the same error

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/m4/szfv1v4s5s14vzlrpqbpxvjr0000gn/T/pip-build-gi2t3cgy/mysqlclient/