# Unable to install pip3 packge after changing default python version from 2.x to 3.x

Tags: python, pip, deb

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pycompile",line 35, in <module>
    from debpython.version i``mport SUPPORTED,debsorted,vrepr, \
  File "/usr/share/python/debpython/version.py", line 24, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
dpkg: error processing package python-pil:amd64 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installaion script returned error exit status 1
Setting up libpython3-dev:``amd64 (3.5.3-1) ...
Setting up python3-dev (3.5.3-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-imaging:
 python-imaging depends on python-pil; however:
  Package python-pil:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-imaging (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kodi-data:
 kodi-data depends on python-imaging; however:
  Package python-imaging is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kodi-data (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-pil:amd64
 python-imaging
 kodi-data
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

`ConfigParser` has been renamed `configparser` in `Python3` for PEP8 compliance.

Answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)