# Support for MySqlTarget in luigi with Python 3?

Tags: python, mysql, luigi

When attempting invoking `from luigi.contrib.mysqldb import MySqlTarget` I get the warning:

```
I get the error: Loading MySQL module without the python package mysql-connector-python.         
This will crash at runtime if MySQL functionality is used.
```

I don't have `mysql` downloaded for my python installation, and neither can I, because `pip install mysql` throws a `ConfigParser` related error. According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser) `mysql` is not compatible with python 3 but there is a forked version called `mysqlclient`. I have this package, but `MySqlTarget` looks like it's written for version 2.

Would the recommended approach here be to fork my own version for `pymysql`, or has somebody already worked on this?

The goal is to create a table locally and then updated a MySQL table within a `luigi.Task`.

Comment: Have you tried installing `mysql-connector-python`? I had the same warning and after installing it through pip (`pip3 install mysql-connector-python`) it works.

Comment: @Bernard I hadn't tried that, no, thanks for the tip. I actually switched to airflow after running into this limitation and haven't looked back. Have you tried it out yet?

Comment: It works with MySqlTarget, however now use SQLAlchemyTarget to support other RDBMS. I had a quick look at Airflow, but not really used it.