# pip3 install mysql ERROR

Tags: python, mysql

I get this error

```
pi@teambaboy:~ $ pip3 install mysql

Collecting mysql

Downloading https://www.piwheels.org/simple/mysql/mysql-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting MySQL-python (from mysql)

Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip

 Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-k38v3y9c/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-build-k38v3y9c/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-k38v3y9c/MySQL-python/

Comment: Try to install pymysql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysqlclient` instead. It's the modern drop-in replacement.

`$ pip install mysqlclient`