# Cant install mysql python connector macOS High Sierra

Tags: python, mysql, macos-sierra, connector

When I try installing mysql-python adaptor with pip3 I get this error message:

```
$ pip3 install mysql-python
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/vx/gzl69zd16lg9s4_xsgpnldv00000gn/T/pip-build-qkxwtgtw/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
    from setup_posix import get_config
  File "/private/var/folders/vx/gzl69zd16lg9s4_xsgpnldv00000gn/T/pip-build-qkxwtgtw/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
/private/var/folders/vx/gzl69zd16lg9s4_xsgpnldv00000gn/T/pip-build- 
qkxwtgtw/mysql-python/
```

Comment: Use mysqlclient `pip install mysqlclient` for Python 3+

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It says it in the error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

[Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Answer (score 0):

1. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'` tells us, that you need ConfigParser to be installed first.
2. MySQL-python-1.2.5 seems pretty old. Not sure if it supports Python 3. Maybe try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mysqlclient ?
3. If you're on Windows, sometimes it helps to download and install from the .whl