# Can't pip install mysql

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to connect to a mySQL server through python on a MacBook Pro, and I need to `pip install mysql` to continue. However when I run that command I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
---------------------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/jc/cn0mjt8s13jfb9w3f42qy27c0000gn/T/pip-install-viy629s3/MySQL-python/
```

Any ideas on how to get pass this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `brew install mysql` maybe will help

Comment: Which python version are you using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Comment: I believe I am using python3.

Comment: `ConfigParser` was renamed to `configparser`  in python3, if you install it for python2, it works just fine. `python2 -m pip install mysql`. Seems like mysql client is not supported by python3 if this is the case.

Comment: @vasia, I got this: -bash: python2: command not found

Comment: also brew intall mysql got this: Error: Failure while executing: git config --local --replace-all homebrew.analyticsmessage true

Comment: what is the output of `ls -la | grep python`?

Comment: @vasia, drwxr-xr-x    5 tmcdo13  staff         170 May 14 11:01 .ipython
              -rw-------       1 tmcdo13  staff          12 May 22 10:52 .python_history

Comment: sorry, my mistake, I meant to ask for the output of `ls -la /usr/bin | grep python`

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel     66736 Jul  8  2016 python
-rwxr-xr-x     5 root   wheel       925 Oct 23  2015 python-config

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        75 Jan 20  2016 python2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        82 Jan 20  2016 python2.6-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6-config
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        75 Jan 20  2016 python2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7

Comment: lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        82 Jan 20  2016 python2.7-config -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel     66736 Jul  8  2016 pythonw
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        76 Jan 20  2016 pythonw2.6 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/pythonw2.6
lrwxr-xr-x     1 root   wheel        76 Jan 20  2016 pythonw2.7 -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pythonw2.7

Comment: @vasia, sorry for the weird response. I couldn't fit it all into one comment.

Comment: okay, so you have python2 installed, and you have both 2.6 and 2.7
You probably want to use 2.7, so to install `mysql` you could run
`python2.7 -m pip install mysql`

Comment: It's saying "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip", but I've used it before?