# configparser in python 3.6 in anaconda

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, configparser

I am trying to port some code from 2.7 to 3.6, and I am having problems with the installing package configparser for py-3.6 in anaconda.

When I execute the following command, I get an error:

```
$ conda install -c anaconda configparser
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
  - configparser -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0']
  - python=3.6
```

The dependencies also gives me the same information:

```
conda info configparser
configparser 3.5.0 py27h5117587_0
---------------------------------
dependencies:
    python >=2.7,<2.8.0a0
```

However, question-[14087598](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598) says the package is available in py-3.6. How should I install this package in anaconda?

(One solution in the above link suggests to install through the python program itself, but I would like to install through anaconda.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package [`configparser`](https://pypi.org/project/configparser/) is a backport of a Python 3.5 standard module to older versions of Python.  Unfortunately, it appears that the [Anaconda version of this package](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/configparser/files) is not packaged for Python 3. 
 However, you are using Python 3.6, so you can simply use the [`configparser` which comes preinstalled with Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) instead of installing anything.

It's possible that the source code you are attempting to port contains a line like this (which will fail if the backport is not installed):

```
from backports import configparser
```

You can *probably* replace that line with the following:

```
import configparser
```

There are minor differences between the 3.5-compatible version installed in the backport and the version provided by 3.6, but the 3.6 version should be backwards compatible for most reasonable use cases.  The main purpose of the `from backports` form is to enable developing 2.x-compatible code in a 3.x-only environment without accidentally using new features that don't exist in the backport.