# Cannot push Django Python project in Heroku

Tags: python, mysql, django, heroku

I try to push the Python project (Python 3.7.0) to Heroku. It's a django project with mysql database linked. But it keeps show that the error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'`. Is really the version 3.7.0 not compatible to Heroku? I try to pip install ConfigParser in the command, but it still not work. Does anyone meet this problem? Here's the error when pushing project in Heroku:

```
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-1fjjz1dy/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
remote:                from setup_posix import get_config
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-1fjjz1dy/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
remote:            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1fjjz1dy/MySQL-python/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to fathomless-citadel-89649.
```

I checked the other solution and installed the mysqlclients but it still cannot be pushed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23978968/2011147

Comment: I have installed the mysqlclient, but still not work.

Comment: This is a separate issue, please post a new question detailing what you mean by "not work".

Comment: I just posted a new question. Here's the link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52127997/still-cannot-push-python-mysql-project-to-heroku-after-pip-install-mysqlclients. Thx