# Still cannot push python mysql project to heroku after pip install mysqlclients

Tags: python, mysql, heroku

I try to push the Python project (Python 3.7.0) to Heroku. It's a django project with mysql database linked. But it keeps show that the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'. From the previous answers recommended by others, it seems that in python 3, I need to install the mysqlclient instead of mysql-python which is for python 2 version. But I have installed such. Is it some problem about library? The error of pushing to heroku is shown as followed. Sorry that if I am stupid since I am still freshman in python.

```
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-1fjjz1dy/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
remote:            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
remote:
remote:            ----------------------------------------
remote:        Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-1fjjz1dy/MySQL-python/
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to fathomless-citadel-89649.
```

The requirements.txt is:

```
asn1crypto==0.24.0
attrs==18.1.0
auth==0.5.3
Automat==0.7.0
beautifulsoup4==4.6.1
blinker==1.4
bs4==0.0.1
certifi==2018.4.16
cffi==1.11.5
chardet==3.0.4
configparser==3.5.0
constantly==15.1.0
cryptography==2.3
cssselect==1.0.3
dj-database-url==0.5.0
dj-static==0.0.6
Django==2.1
django-bootstrap3==10.0.1
django-forms-bootstrap==3.1.0
dnspython==1.15.0
eventlet==0.24.1
falcon==1.4.1
greenlet==0.4.14
gunicorn==19.9.0
hyperlink==18.0.0
idna==2.7
incremental==17.5.0
lxml==4.2.4
misaka==2.1.0
mongoengine==0.15.3
monotonic==1.5
mysql==0.0.1
mysql-connector==2.1.6
mysqlclient==1.3.13
parsel==1.5.0
pyasn1==0.4.4
pyasn1-modules==0.2.2
pycparser==2.18
PyDispatcher==2.0.5
PyHamcrest==1.9.0
pymongo==3.7.1
PyMySQL==0.9.2
pyOpenSSL==18.0.0
python-mimeparse==1.6.0
pytz==2018.5
queuelib==1.5.0
requests==2.19.1
Scrapy==1.5.1
service-identity==17.0.0
six==1.11.0
static3==0.7.0
Twisted==18.7.0
typed-ast==1.1.0
urllib3==1.23
views==0.3
virtualenv==16.0.0
w3lib==1.19.0
Werkzeug==0.14.1
zope.interface==4.5.0
psycopg2>=2.6.1
```

Comment: You've still got mysql-python in your requirements or pipfile. You should remove it.

Comment: Just post the requirements.txt here, seems it was removed.

Comment: But you have "mysql", which [as its entry on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/mysql/) shows is a virtual package that installs mysql-python. Remove that, and also remove mysql-connector which you don't need.

Comment: Thx. If in the python module, I import mysql.connector for some function application. Do I still need to remove mysql-connector?

Comment: Well no, of course not if you're using it, but you shouldn't need it in a Django app and even more so if you are already using mysqlclient. What are you using it for?

Comment: To connect to a mysql database in the function

Comment: But a) you are using Django which manages all that for you, so you shouldn't be connecting directly to the db and b) you also have mysqlclient which does the same thing. You really don't need both.

Comment: Thx for the reply. But I need to use the python project to process the data of django and store the processed data in mysql and export such to show in django edited web. Here's my workflow. Is it OK?