# How do I fix this Flask MySQL error when pushing to Heroku?

Tags: python, mysql, flask

I'm trying to deploy my Flask app on Heroku and am running into some issues when I push to master. I'm running on Windows with Python 2.7. I take it there's an issue with a dependency for MySQL Flask, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Does anyone know how to fix this and get running? Very frustrated.

```
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fe/61/521257e46b9cc1345ec574670446b3a31fd35eb74db2b37c01fdc1cd741c/mysql_connector_python-8.0.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (249kB)
remote:        Collecting MySQL-python==1.2.5 (from -r /tmp/build_5f0535031fd60ed1954d14f2229425d2/requirements.txt (line 29))
remote:          Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108kB)
remote:            Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
remote:            Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:              File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-jjq_wu6o/MySQL-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
remote:                from setup_posix import get_config
remote:              File "/tmp/pip-build-jjq_wu6o/MySQL-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
remote:                from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
remote:            ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Comment: As of https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes. "To specify a Python runtime, add a runtime.txt file to your app’s root directory that declares the exact version number to use." In your case that should be `python-2.7`.