# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tu6ygqzj/mysql-python/

Tags: python, pip, mysql-python

I am using python3 to install mysql-python package. So, when I run

> pip install mysql-python,

it gives me error.

Tried using

> pip install --upgrade setuptools

It shows

```
Collecting mysql-python
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/e9/51b544da85a36a68debe7a7091f068d802fc515a3a202652828c73453cad/MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-tu6ygqzj/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-build-tu6ygqzj/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    **ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'**

----------------------------------------
***Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-tu6ygqzj/mysql-python/***
```

Successfully installed with all files in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmysql-python%5D+ImportError+No+module+named+ConfigParser

Answer (score 12):

I guess you need to install the following:

```
pip install mysqlclient
```

In Python 3, [`ConfigParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) has been renamed to [`configparser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html) for PEP 8 compliance.

> `mysqlclient` is a fork of `mysql-python`, with Python 3 support.

Kindly make sure you have installed the following before installing `mysqlclient`:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: what has to be done for amazon linux 2 since it is giving me error '1 packages excluded due to repository priority protections'

Answer (score 1):

For Lunix and Mac Machines, install the mysqlclient pre-requisites via:

**Debian / Ubuntu  -**  `sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev`

**Red Hat / CentOS  -**  `sudo yum install python-devel mysql-devel`

**macOS (Homebrew)  -** `brew install mysql-client`

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do this before that so after this it command work:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```