# port audio error - "No module named ConfigParser"

Tags: python, pyaudio

i am attempting to install the port audio module and in doing so it says that there is no module named "ConfigParser". I understand that the newer version of the module is configparser but im not sure how to install it. Does anyone have any solutions because this is what the terminal reports:

PS F:> pip install port audio

```
    import ConfigParser
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'**
----------------------------------------**
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/q/14087598/797196 - very helpful

Comment: i did however the comments only suggests an alternative for downloading SQL and not a solution to the configparser error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
from configparser import ConfjgParser
```

This should hopefully make the other import treat it like the old version.