# Unable to install mysql-python library in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, mysql-python

I tried installing mysql-python in ubuntu but I remained unsuccessful, I was using Win10 before and never encountered this problem.

> I used `pip3 install MySql-python`

I have encountered following error:

```
Using cached MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip (108 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j3febudn/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-j3febudn/mysql-python/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-j3febudn/mysql-python/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-j3febudn/mysql-python/
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-j3febudn/mysql-python/setup.py", line 13, in <module>
        from setup_posix import get_config
      File "/tmp/pip-install-j3febudn/mysql-python/setup_posix.py", line 2, in <module>
        from ConfigParser import SafeConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: MySQL on its page has special module for Python. Maybe use it instead of `MySql-python` - See [connector/python](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) - there is even version specially for Ubuntu 20.04. I use it with Linux Mint 19.3 based on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: BTW: doc for [connector/python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html) - you can use it directly or in SQLAlchemy.

Comment: @furas THankyou, That actually worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be related to: [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

In short, your module is not python3 compatible, use another module, or use python2, but this is not recommended, since python2 is going deprecated.

Comment: I tried the solution you gave in above comment. But nothing is working. I am facing same error with  MySql-python, mysqlpython.

Comment: Does your error message contain ```ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'``` like before?

Comment: Yes, it's same. Maybe I will have to use some other library, but I was used to this library.