# no module named ConfigParser

Tags: python, speech-recognition, python-3.8, pyaudio, portaudio

I am trying to install port audio because my code (uses pyaudio and speechrecognition) said to build and install the port audio bindings first. Anyway, when I said pip install port audio it said this:

```
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\stewa\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\stewa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nkbwpxww\\audio.coders\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\stewa\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-nkbwpxww\\audio.coders\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\stewa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-y8d_hj4c'
         cwd: C:\Users\stewa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nkbwpxww\audio.coders\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\stewa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-nkbwpxww\audio.coders\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
        import ConfigParser
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

I says no module named ConfigParser do you know what i should do. If it is any help im using python 3.8.5 and windows 10
thanks

Comment: I would have expected `from configparser import ConfigParser`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Answer (score 7):

The package is most probably not python-3 compatible.

As [stated in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087705/11984670) `ConfigParser` has been renamed to `configparser` in python-3.
You might want to consider either running it via python-2 (not recommended since it's deprecated) or use another updated package (if available)

Comment: @STEMguy24 you could **try** downloading it and changing the `import` statement locally (`from configparser import Configparser`) before doing `pip install .` But who knows what other things may need changing to make it python 3 compatible... if it was just the import then they would probably have done it already.