# Problem with Installation of audio.coders: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'"

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I have a problem installing audio.coder in python3.

```
Requirement already satisfied: configparser in c:\users/lib\site-packages(installed already) (4.0.2).

Error:

Using cached audio.coders-4.0.2.tar.gz (682 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [6 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/18/dg9nnkwj33qd7hwq8nmkqp1r0000gn/T/pip-install-pwqm3pw1/audio-coders_ffbe7e1c37a748f9b4da82b85363aaee/setup.py", line 5, in <module>
          import ConfigParser
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ConfigParser'
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? Because it looks like the package you are trying to install is not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python 3 ImportError: No module named 'ConfigParser'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14087598/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-configparser)

Comment: I tried to implement audio coder and I have got this error, i am using python 3

Comment: OK, Python 3, but as I've said, it looks like the package you are using (`audio.coders`) isn't compatible with Python 3. [It was last updated 2015](https://pypi.org/project/audio.coders/#history). As explained [in the answer I linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14087705/2745495), that `audio.coders` module is importing `ConfigParser`, but in Python 3 it has been renamed to `configparser`. Which means, that package was not yet updated for Python 3.

Comment: Right, How do I install audio.coders? I have been renamed it to configparser , it seems dose not work. I tried to resolve these errors to install audio.coders but cant find a solution for it.