# Having problems connecting to MySQL database with Tornado (OSX Lion; python 2.7.1)

Tags: python, mysql, phpmyadmin, tornado

I have both Tornado and XAMPP installed on my computer. Traditionally, I used PhpMyAdmin for all my MySQL work; however, I would like to make this work with Tornado as well. When I try to connect to MySQL through Tornado, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__server.py", line 20, in <module>
    class Application(tornado.web.Application):
  File "__server.py", line 40, in Application
    password=options.mysql_password
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/tornado-2.4.1-py2.7.egg/tornado/database.py",     line 59, in __init__
    args = dict(conv=CONVERSIONS, use_unicode=True, charset="utf8",
NameError: global name 'CONVERSIONS' is not defined
```

This error leads me to believe that Tornado doesn't think I have MySQL installed on my computer.

Here is the pertinent Tornado code off of `__server.py` if it makes any difference:

```
import tornado.database
import tornado.options
import unicodedata
from tornado.options import define, options

define("port", default=8888, help="run on the given port", type=int)
define("mysql_host", default="localhost", help="database host") #127.0.0.1:3306 – this was the      default (should I change it? I didn't get this far in the setup process to know)
define("mysql_database", default="Godzillian1", help="database name")
define("mysql_user", default="root", help="database user")
define("mysql_password", default="", help="database password")

class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    self.db = tornado.database.Connection(
        host=options.mysql_host, 
        database=options.mysql_database,
        user=options.mysql_user, 
        password=options.mysql_password
    )
```

Thus my question: Do I need to change something in a Tornado config file or something to that effect? Currently any MySQL files are located in my XAMPP folder. That seems problematic to me, but before I move everything, I would like to check. Or, do I need to "re-download" MySql completely? Or is it something with the Tornado `__server.py` itself. (Note: for the purposes of this, I removed the password and made `username=root`, in trying to figure out a solution to this.)

EDIT:
I have successfully installed both MySQL5(64bit) and MySQL-Python, yet I am still getting this same error of `NameError: global name 'CONVERSATIONS' is not defined`. Should I install the 32bit version of MySQL so that it is compatible with MySQL-Python? (I thought that Lion needed the 64bit MySQL...but I clearly know nothing right now). This is perplexing!

Thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Tornado to me.

Comment: What makes you think that this is a bug of some sort? Anything in particular?

Comment: The fact that it's happening inside Tornado itself.

Comment: Okay, I see what you're saying. Do you think it makes a difference where MySQL is installed versus where Tornado is installed? If it were a bug in Tornado, as you suggest, I don't think this would matter...

Comment: As long as Tornado can find the MySQL DB-API adapter, it shouldn't matter where they're installed.

Comment: Pretty sure you don't have MySQLdb installed. `pip install mysql-python` should do it. Tornado should definitely give you a clearer error message, but as they've removed the database component for 3.0 I doubt that will happen.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. This is exactly what I just figured out and was in the the process of installing to see if it fixed my problem. But yeah, the error isn't very intuitive. Hopefully that's the problem though.

Comment: So, I finally got mysql-python to install and...it made no difference. It's definitely installed though, seeing as my response to `pip install mysql-python` was `Requirement already satisfied ...`. Any other thoughts on how I can get this to work??

Comment: if you run python from the command line and type `import tornado.database`, what happens?

Comment: Thanks cole for your advice. I actually did get it work, after about 2 days of installing, re-installing, and configuring. It was a bit tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution to this problem. MySQL-Python had to be (re)installed *properly*. I also had to switch my python 2.7.1 to the 32bit version rather than 64bit, and on OSX *Lion*, MySQL must be installed as a 64bit. Compatibility seems to be difficult to achieve easily, so another viable option many people used to install both MySQL and MySQL-Python was to install/use [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php) and then use these two commands:

```
sudo port install py26-mysql 
sudo port install mysql5-server
```

Regardless, see this SO question for a more comprehensive explanation of the solution if this didn't suffice:
[How to install MySQLdb (Python data access library to MySQL) on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x)