# How do I remove a python egg?

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

This post ([How to install MySQLdb (Python data access library to MySQL) on Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x)) recommends cleaning up a MySQLdb installation by removing a python egg:

"Step 3c: Remove the egg under Users/$USER/.python-eggs"

I have no idea how to navigate to that location. I thought the eggs where in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ ?

Please help.

Comment: Usually they are... The person who wrote that post seems to have a non-default location for their eggs.

Answer (score 0):

Ususally my approach is to figure out where the first **init**.py file for the package is

For example

```
In [4]: import django 

In [5]: django.__file__
Out[5]: '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/__init__.pyc'
```

so essentially

when you do

```
import module 
module.__file__
```

However I have to say this is not the best way I would suggest use better package management or pip preferably with virtualenv to manage your python related package management issues.