# Python: multiple installations

Tags: python, mysql, installation, version

I was successfully using python in my programs and importing necessary modules including MySQL. However, to get IDLE on my computer I downloaded a new copy of python. I'm really not sure what I did or what happened but when I try to run a program now that uses MySQL I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "MyFile.py", line 11, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so, 2): Symbol not found: _mysql_affected_rows
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQL_python-1.2.4b4-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/_mysql.so
```

any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually I fixed the problem by reinstalling MySQLdb following the step found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448429/how-to-install-mysqldb-python-data-access-library-to-mysql-on-mac-os-x#1448476). I'm not sure how well this will work for additional modules though